# BIDS throws an exception trying to display blobs

Tags: blob, firebird, olap, bids, olap-cube

I don't know if this is the correct place to ask but here goes;

i've been using Microsoft SQL 2008 R2 Business Inteligence Development Studio to create an analysis service, ultimatly to build an OLAP cube

when i want to explore data in in my data source view, i get an exception. for some reason BIDS can't or won't parse the binary data in a column.

the exception that is thrown, looks like an unhandled exception of BIDS. the last line of the message is `To replace this default dialog please handle the dataError event`

the first part of the error message:

`The following exception occured in the datagridView:`

`System.argumentException: Parameter is not valid.`
`at system.drawing.image.fromstream(Stream stream, boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, boolean validateImageData)
at...`

the database used is a firebired 2.5 database connected through IBProvider v3 ODBC driver. i had issues before, i changed the code page to win1252, west europe so it would parse text fields correctly.

on the websites of firebird i found that binary fields can have subtypes, this one is 0 = not defined so firebird will save the data byte for byte.

when i look inside the field, it has some rtf data.

has anyone experienced this, or can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Edit:** added the exception

**Edit:** when i change the subtype to 1 (text) there is no problem. but this would require me to update 431 tables. shouldn't there be an easier way?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: ah, i see i forgot to add that one... one second please

Comment: i've added the part the exception, but honestly, to me it seems like an unhandled exception in BIDS.